# Buffered Reader reads only certain Lines java FileReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am using buffered reader to get data line by line from a textfile.
This is my code.

```
    File f1=new File("skdata//comp//"+l1.getText()+"//grplist.txt");

    try {
        FileReader fr1=new FileReader(f1);  
        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);


        while (br1.readLine()!=null)
        {

            m1.addElement(br1.readLine());
        }




    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gcreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gcreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        cmb1.setModel(m1);
```

I have getting result as only certain lines only from buffered reader
Hope your helps
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just looks over my code and find the problem. I used readLine twice. So it skips lines.
So I changed the code as follows.

```
File f1=new File("skdata//comp//"+l1.getText()+"//grplist.txt");


    try {
        FileReader fr1=new FileReader(f1);  
        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);

   String str1;
        while ((str1=br1.readLine())!=null)
        {
            m1.addElement(str1);
        }

        //





    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gcreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gcreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```